# Saving Data from form to database using AngularJS and php

Tags: javascript, php, database, angularjs

I'm pretty new in angular.
i created a modal window to user share story and after that show it in body:

**html**

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary new-story" ng-click="showPopup()">New Story</button>


            <div class="wroteStory img-rounded" ng-repeat="story in sentCompose">

                <h1 class="s-label"><i><label for="subject">Subject :</label></i></h1>
                <h5>{{story.subject}}</h5>


                <h1 class="s-label"><i><label for="body">Full Story :</label></i></h1>
                <h6>{{story.body}}</h6>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove($index)"> Delete </button>
                <hr/>
            </div>
```

**js**

```
app.controller('aboutController', function($scope,ngProgress) {


$scope.popupVisible = false;
$scope.showPopup = function(){
    $scope.popupVisible = true;
    $scope.composeStory = {};
}
$scope.closePopup = function(){
    $scope.popupVisible = false;
}


$scope.composeStory = {};
$scope.sentCompose = [];

$scope.sendStory = function() {
   $scope.sentCompose.push($scope.composeStory);
    $scope.popupVisible = false;


    $http.post("insert.php", data).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

    });

};
```

i want to save data from this form to database ? 
Thx in advance

Comment: This is too broad. Just Google PHP and database and you'll get plenty of tutorial.

Comment: please help if you can , i've google it already and can't made it

Comment: If you can't follow any of the tutorials posted on the Internet already, how will you follow one posted here?

Comment: because they are not simple as i want , as i said before i'm new in angular

Comment: Why do you think it would be any simpler here? Also, if you read my first comment again, you'll notice I said PHP and database. I didn't mention Angular. Angular cannot interact with a database.

Comment: what does `new to angular` have to do with saving to database in php?

Comment: would plz help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

With limited information you provided, i will try to help you on this. When you ask questions, please show what output your are getting, what your debugging says. It will be helpful for others to understand your problem and suggest you some solution. Here is my suggestions

1) I could not see scope of your `$http.post("insert.php", **data**)` data variable make sure that you have serialized data in it.

2) Check in firebug whether your request is being sent or not. If you can see the request then see what is the response you are getting

3) As you have success handler always have a error handler for any Ajax call, it is a best practice and saves lot of your time in debugging

My suggestions are based on assumption that your `insert.php` is tested for inserting data properly. If not you have to follow what John Conde told

Answer (score 0):

first you should be able to create a db in mysql and creat a table for that .
then you should be able to connect them with php like this :

```
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "angular";
$pass = "angular";
$database = "angular";
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db($database,$con);
```